# sorting output by incrementing IP in mysql

Tags: mysql, order-by

I want an incrementing list of IP #'s in a subnet to display on a php web page in a table. Right now, `10.1.2.3` would display after `10.1.2.10` in the sequence.

My current query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM `ip` WHERE `subnet` LIKE '10.1.2.0/24' ORDER BY ip;
```

What query do I need?

My IP field is 16 character `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort this using [**`INET_ATON`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton):

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `ip` WHERE `subnet` LIKE '10.1.2.0/24' ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip);
```

**Data:**

```
mysql> select * from ip;
+------------+-------------+
| ip         | subnet      |
+------------+-------------+
| 10.1.2.1   | 10.1.2.0/24 |
| 10.1.2.10  | 10.1.2.0/24 |
| 10.1.2.123 | 10.1.2.0/24 |
| 10.1.2.3   | 10.1.2.0/24 |
+------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Test:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `ip` WHERE `subnet` LIKE '10.1.2.0/24' ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip);
+------------+-------------+
| ip         | subnet      |
+------------+-------------+
| 10.1.2.1   | 10.1.2.0/24 |
| 10.1.2.3   | 10.1.2.0/24 |
| 10.1.2.10  | 10.1.2.0/24 |
| 10.1.2.123 | 10.1.2.0/24 |
+------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```